# How to read multipart/form-data content from request body in Spring WebFlux filter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

I am trying to filter multipart/form-data content, but don't know how to get access to request body. I found DefaultPartHttpMessageReader class, but for now I have no idea how to parse content using it.